# jQueryMobile+PhoneGap+iOS 11: Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState() to change session history URL

Tags: jquery-mobile, phonegap

Starting with iPhone OS 11.3, my app is broken with the following error:

```
SecurityError: Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState() to change session history URL from file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E73A3E4A-D961-4943-BAA3-7845E755F6A0/myplaceonline.app/www/index.html#/?phonegap=true to https://myplaceonline.com/?phonegap=true. Protocols, domains, ports, usernames, and passwords must match.
url:
file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E73A3E4A-D961-4943-BAA3-7845E755F6A0/myplaceonline.app/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
line #: 3 (31672)
```

The way I've always done it (and this continues to work with Android):

1. [PhoneGap app](https://github.com/myplaceonline/myplaceonline_phonegap) loads JQM in an [index.html page](https://github.com/myplaceonline/myplaceonline_phonegap/blob/master/www/index.html).
2. A JQM [`mobileinit`](https://github.com/myplaceonline/myplaceonline_phonegap/blob/master/www/index.html#L30) event handler is attached which registers a `pageloaded` event handler which ultimately calls [loadHomepage](https://github.com/myplaceonline/myplaceonline_phonegap/blob/master/www/js/index.js#L84).
3. loadHomepage sets `$.mobile.path.documentBase` and the `href` attribute of the `base` tag to my remote server (https://myplaceonline.com/) and calls `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "/", { allowSamePageTransition: true, transition: 'none', reloadPage: true, changeHash: true });` to load the remote homepage.
4. This ultimately drives JQM to call replaceState which fails with the security error:

   `replaceState@[native code]
   squash@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E73A3E4A-D961-4943-BAA3-7845E755F6A0/myplaceonline.app/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3:31672
   go@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E73A3E4A-D961-4943-BAA3-7845E755F6A0/myplaceonline.app/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:4:322
   navigate@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E73A3E4A-D961-4943-BAA3-7845E755F6A0/myplaceonline.app/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:4:1598`

The purpose of all of the above is so that I don't navigate away from `file:///` because if I were to do that, I would lose access to all native phone JS APIs through PhoneGap. This works on older versions of iOS and continues to work on Android.

Any ideas on an alternative way to do this to get around the tighter security on newer versions of iOS? Alternatively, I see there are issues like https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5465 which suggest a method of disabling history and I'm wondering if this would be another workaround and what I would lose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code to a `mobileinit` handler fixes the issue:

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
```